# Sort works but the toggle not working

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am making a simple sort function using jquery, i would like to toggle the sort from alpha to z and z to alpha.

the first condition is works, but i unable to resort (z to alpha)..

html:

```
<a href="#">Toggle Sort</a>

<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Bascket</li>
    <li>Umberla</li>
    <li>Zebra</li>
    <li>Good Student</li>
    <li>Liable</li>
 </ul>
```

my js:

```
$("a").on("click", function(){

   var elements = $("ul").find("li").get();

   var sorted = elements.sort(function(a, b){
       if($(a).text() > $(b).text()){
           return 1;
       }

       if($(a).text() < $(b).text()){
           return -1;
       }
    });

    $("ul").html(sorted);

});
```

what is wrong here..

here is the [hre is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Hu/)

Thanks in advance..

I updating the working example: [here is the working example of jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaR9j/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swap a toggle-state to get the real *sorting-direction*, that can be done simply like this:

```
var elements = $("ul").find("li");
var state = false;

$("a").on("click", function () {
    state = !state;

    var sorted = elements.sort(function (a, b) {
        var _a = $(a).text();
        var _b = $(b).text();

        if (_a > _b) return state ? 1 : -1;
        if (_a < _b) return state ? -1 : 1;
    });

    $("ul").html(sorted);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/sbWV3/3

**Update**

To make the sorting-function a bit *"simpler"*, you can replace these lines:

```
var _a = $(a).text();
var _b = $(b).text();

if (_a > _b) return state ? 1 : -1;
if (_a < _b) return state ? -1 : 1;
```

with this simple 1-line ternary-statement operator:

```
return !state || ($(a).text() > $(b).text()) ? 1 : -1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/sbWV3

Comment: @NOX Thanks :-* (I've updated it, to make this a bit *simpler*)

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Hu/19/)**

You need an algorithm
to find the current sorting order:

```
$("a").on("click", function () {
    var type = 'asc';
    if ($(this).data('desc') === true) {
        type = 'desc';
        $(this).data('desc', false);
    }
    else {
        $(this).data('desc', true);
    }

    var elements = $("ul").find("li").get();
    var sorted = elements.sort(function(a, b){
             if($(a).text() > $(b).text()){ return  1; }
        else if($(a).text() < $(b).text()){ return -1; }
        return 0;
    });

    if (type == 'desc') {
        sorted.reverse();
    }

    $("ul").html(sorted);
});
```

Comment: this is not working.. (as a first click my list need to start from apple, on toggle it need to start from zebra..

Comment: @3gwebtrain Did you check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Hu/1/)? It works for me. What error you gave?

Comment: @yckart OK :D, i didn't attention to `toggle`. Added another solution for toggling :)

Comment: @3gwebtrain fixed, check that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a  *direction* flag ( also you should return `0` when its equal)

**http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Hu/14/**

```
var dir=-1;

$("a").on("click", function(){

dir=dir*-1;

   var elements = $("ul").find("li").get();

   var sorted = elements.sort(function(a, b){

       if($.trim($(a).text()) > $.trim($(b).text())){
           return 1*dir;
       }

       if($.trim($(a).text()) < $.trim($(b).text())){
           return -1* dir;
       }
       return 0;
    });

   $("ul").html(sorted);


})
```

*- `trim` can be removed. just wanted to make sure there are no space and stuff like that.*

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `class` after the initial sort and then just use the `reverse()` method:

```
$("a").on("click", function () {
    var parentList = $("ul");
    var elements = parentList.children("li").get();
    var sorted = !parentList.is(".sorted") ? function () {
            elements.sort(function (a, b) {
                var a1 = $(a).text().substring(0, 1);
                var b1 = $(b).text().substring(0, 1);
                parentList.addClass("sorted");
                if (a1 > b1) {return 1;}
                if (a1 < b1) {return -1;}
                return 0;
            });
            return elements;
        } : elements.reverse();
    parentList.append(sorted);
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/GMDYV/3/)